# Android build for limited function device

Tags: android, embedded, android-source

I'm trying to build a limited-functionality Android system for our device, which needs to boot quickly, but everything we do seems to slow it down.

For example, our device has no camera, no bluetooth, no wifi, but turning them off wholesale in various `/system/etc/init/*.rc` files seems to actually slow it down, due to the interdependencies of Android.  The services that are turned off end up restarting, or causing timeouts in Settings, for example.

(Android is on the device for its' UI, not for its connectivity abilities.)

Do you have any suggestions for how to do this?  Surely Android for cars, TVs and tablets have had to deal with these issues before.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things)?

Comment: Have you read [Optimizing Boot Times](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/boot-times)?
Do you measure startup performance? https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/boot-times#bootchart

Comment: No, both links are new to me.  We're sort of working in a bubble.  Thanks for both links!

Comment: Been focusing mostly in init*.rc   The kernel is fast enough for us now.  It's init that's our bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what you did exactly, but if you tried to not start HAL services on startup they might just be started dynamically later. If you are using Android 8 or newer you could merge multiple HALs in one process. But I doubt that this will give you any significant speed-up.

Android does provide a guide on how to optimize boot times: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/boot-times. **However**, you will notice that they focus on the bootloader, kernel, file system, SELinux, and parallelizing init. The elephant in the room is `Zygote`. It takes forever to start because it preloads the whole Android SDK.

From its history, Android did not care too much about startup times, because you typically do not restart Android. Instead, they rely on Suspend-to-RAM.

You should think about what you want to have your user experience early. Example: for Automotive Android, Google needs to support a rear-view camera that is available within two seconds after boot. They achieve that by a second, faster stack that provides first images before the application SDK is started and takes over. See https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/camera-hal